# Mensaje: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

he estado buscando en las muchas consultas anteriores sobre este mismo tema, pero no encuentro la respuesta a mi problema. Tengo una consulta doble: dependiendo de un parámetro se hace una inserción de nuevo registro, o una modificación de uno existente. Pasando los mismos parámetros para las dos consultas, en la de modificar no tengo ningún problema, el registro se modifica, pero si, pasando los mismos datos, intento un registro nuevo, me arroja el error. 
Ésta es la consulta:

```
public static function crearModificarProyecto ($nombre, $fecha_comienzo, 
                 $fecha_final, $pesoDiana, $intervalo, $caloriasDia, $estiramientos,  
                 $tiempo_estiramientos, $cardio, $tiempo_cardio, $pesas, 
                 $tiempo_pesas, $usuario, $descripcion, $activo, $nombreAModificar) {
      // Comprobamos si es un proyecto a crear o a modificar
      if ($nombreAModificar == "") {
         $consultaTipo = "INSERT INTO Proyecto (nombre, fecha_comienzo, fecha_final, "
                 . "pesoDiana, intervalo, caloriasDia, estiramientos, tiempo_estiramientos, "
                 . "cardio, tiempo_cardio, pesas, tiempo_pesas, usuario, descripcion, "
                 . "activo) VALUES (:nombre, :fecha_comienzo, :fecha_final, :pesoDiana "
                 . ":intervalo, :caloriasDia, :estiramientos, :tiempo_estiramientos, "
                 . ":cardio, :tiempo_cardio, :pesas, :tiempo_pesas, :usuario, "
                 . ":descripcion, :activo)";
      } else {
         $consultaTipo = "UPDATE Proyecto SET "
                 . "nombre = :nombre, "
                 . "fecha_comienzo = :fecha_comienzo, "
                 . "fecha_final = :fecha_final, "
                 . "pesoDiana = :pesoDiana, "
                 . "intervalo = :intervalo, "
                 . "caloriasDia = :caloriasDia, "
                 . "estiramientos = :estiramientos, "
                 . "tiempo_estiramientos = :tiempo_estiramientos, "
                 . "cardio = :cardio, "
                 . "tiempo_cardio = :tiempo_cardio, "
                 . "pesas = :pesas, "
                 . "tiempo_pesas = :tiempo_pesas, "
                 . "usuario = :usuario, "
                 . "descripcion = :descripcion, "
                 . "activo = :activo "
                 . "WHERE usuario = :usuario and nombre = :nombreAModificar";
      }
      self::accesoDB();
      try {
         $consulta = $consultaTipo;
         $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($consulta);
         $resultado->bindParam(":nombreAModificar", $nombreAModificar);
         $resultado->bindParam(":nombre", $nombre);
         $resultado->bindParam(":fecha_comienzo", $fecha_comienzo);
         $resultado->bindParam(":fecha_final", $fecha_final);
         $resultado->bindParam(":pesoDiana", $pesoDiana);
         $resultado->bindParam(":intervalo", $intervalo);
         $resultado->bindParam(":caloriasDia", $caloriasDia);
         $resultado->bindParam(":estiramientos", $estiramientos);
         $resultado->bindParam(":tiempo_estiramientos", $tiempo_estiramientos);
         $resultado->bindParam(":cardio", $cardio);
         $resultado->bindParam(":tiempo_cardio", $tiempo_cardio);
         $resultado->bindParam(":pesas", $pesas);
         $resultado->bindParam(":tiempo_pesas", $tiempo_pesas);
         $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
         $resultado->bindParam(":descripcion", $descripcion);
         $resultado->bindParam(":activo", $activo);
         $resultado->execute();
         if ($resultado) {
            return ["exito" => "El proyecto ha sido creado/modificado.", 
                "Resultado" => $resultado];
         } else {
            return ["fracaso" => "No se ha podido crear/modificar el proyecto",
                "Resultado" => $resultado];
         }
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
         $resultado = ["error" => "Hubo un error en la consulta"
             , "codigo" => "Código de error: " . $e->getCode()
             , "Mensaje" => "Mensaje: " . $e->getMessage()
             , "Resultado" => $resultado];
      }
      return $resultado;
   }
```

Y este es el mensaje de error:

```
Mensaje: "Mensaje: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"
​
Resultado: {…}
​​
queryString: "INSERT INTO Proyecto (nombre, fecha_comienzo, fecha_final, pesoDiana, intervalo, caloriasDia, estiramientos, tiempo_estiramientos, cardio, tiempo_cardio, pesas, tiempo_pesas, usuario, descripcion, activo) 
VALUES (:nombre, :fecha_comienzo, :fecha_final, :pesoDiana :intervalo, :caloriasDia, :estiramientos, :tiempo_estiramientos, :cardio, :tiempo_cardio, :pesas, :tiempo_pesas, :usuario, :descripcion, :activo)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conviene que escribas este tipo de consultas identadas. Rápidamente podrás evaluarlos y comparar cada valor.

Al identarla se ve claramente que te falta una coma después del parámetro `:pesoDiana`, de ahí el error.

Intenta escribir una consulta menos confusa, sin tantas contatenaciones:

```
     $consultaTipo = "INSERT INTO Proyecto (
                                                nombre, 
                                                fecha_comienzo, 
                                                fecha_final, 
                                                pesoDiana, 
                                                intervalo, 
                                                caloriasDia, 
                                                estiramientos, 
                                                tiempo_estiramientos, 
                                                cardio, 
                                                tiempo_cardio, 
                                                pesas, 
                                                tiempo_pesas, 
                                                usuario, 
                                                descripcion, 
                                                activo
                                            ) VALUES (
                                                :nombre, 
                                                :fecha_comienzo, 
                                                :fecha_final, 
                                                :pesoDiana, -- Aquí había error, borra este comentario
                                                :intervalo, 
                                                :caloriasDia, 
                                                :estiramientos, 
                                                :tiempo_estiramientos,
                                                :cardio, 
                                                :tiempo_cardio, 
                                                :pesas, 
                                                :tiempo_pesas, 
                                                :usuario, 
                                                :descripcion, 
                                                :activo
                                            )";
```

### Diferenciar el `INSERT` y el `UPDATE`

Deberías diferenciar el `INSERT` y el `UPDATE`, porque son dos consultas de naturaleza distinta. Podrías quizá crear una función para cada una y en el contexto verificar si `$nombreAModificar` está vacío o no para llamar una u otra.

De todos modos, aquí te muestro una forma de diferenciarlas. Como podrás comprobar, la consulta del `UPDATE` llevaría más parámetros que la del `INSERT`.

Aquí voy a echar mano de otra posibilidad que tiene PDO que es usar marcadores de posición `?`. Eso permitirá crear en cada parte del `if` un array con los valores que han de usarse en el `execute()` y PDO nos da la ventaja de poder pasar los valores ahí en forma de array, lo cual simplifica muchísimo para casos como estos, porque según el caso estaremos pasando los valores exactos en `$mParams`. Eso sí, debes hilar fino cuando usas marcadores de posición, porque si pones una variable en el orden incorrecto los datos asumirían valores erróneos.

Aquí te dejo el código. De todos modos, es mejor no mezclar dos tipos de consulta diferentes.

```
public static function crearModificarProyecto ($nombre, $fecha_comienzo, 
                 $fecha_final, $pesoDiana, $intervalo, $caloriasDia, $estiramientos,  
                 $tiempo_estiramientos, $cardio, $tiempo_cardio, $pesas, 
                 $tiempo_pesas, $usuario, $descripcion, $activo, $nombreAModificar) {
      // Comprobamos si es un proyecto a crear o a modificar
      if ($nombreAModificar == "") {
            $consultaTipo = "INSERT INTO Proyecto (
                        nombre, 
                        fecha_comienzo, 
                        fecha_final, 
                        pesoDiana, 
                        intervalo, 
                        caloriasDia, 
                        estiramientos, 
                        tiempo_estiramientos, 
                        cardio, 
                        tiempo_cardio, 
                        pesas, 
                        tiempo_pesas, 
                        usuario, 
                        descripcion, 
                        activo
                        ) VALUES (
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?,
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?,
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?, 
                        ?
                    )";
            $mParams=array($nombre, $fecha_comienzo,$fecha_final, $pesoDiana, $intervalo, $caloriasDia,
                           $estiramientos, $tiempo_estiramientos, $cardio, $tiempo_cardio, $pesas, 
                           $tiempo_pesas, $usuario, $descripcion, $activo);                 

      } else {
         $consultaTipo = "UPDATE Proyecto SET 
                            nombre = ?,
                            fecha_comienzo = ?,
                            fecha_final = ?,
                            pesoDiana = ?,
                            intervalo = ?,
                            caloriasDia = ?,
                            estiramientos = ?,
                            tiempo_estiramientos = ?,
                            cardio = ?,
                            tiempo_cardio = ?,
                            pesas = ?,
                            tiempo_pesas = ?,
                            usuario = ?,
                            descripcion = ?,
                            activo = ?
                        WHERE usuario = ? and nombre = ?";
            $mParams=array($nombre, $fecha_comienzo,$fecha_final, $pesoDiana, $intervalo, $caloriasDia,
                           $estiramientos, $tiempo_estiramientos, $cardio, $tiempo_cardio, $pesas, 
                           $tiempo_pesas, $usuario, $descripcion, $activo, $nombre, $nombreAModificar);                 

      }
      self::accesoDB();
      try {
         // $consulta = $consultaTipo; Puedes pasar $consultaTipo sin mas
         $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($consultaTipo);
         $resultado->execute($mParams);
         if ($resultado) {
            return ["exito" => "El proyecto ha sido creado/modificado.", 
                "Resultado" => $resultado];
         } else {
            return ["fracaso" => "No se ha podido crear/modificar el proyecto",
                "Resultado" => $resultado];
         }
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
         $resultado = ["error" => "Hubo un error en la consulta"
             , "codigo" => "Código de error: " . $e->getCode()
             , "Mensaje" => "Mensaje: " . $e->getMessage()
             , "Resultado" => $resultado];
      }
      return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Efectivamente, me faltaba una coma. Lo he indentado como me indicas (sigo muchos de tus consejos, mi código está mejorando). Lamentablemente, me sigue dando el mismo error, y aparentemente está ya todo bien.

Comment: OK @RaúlSoriaOrtiz se me escapó revisar el binding. Observa que en el `try` hay `16` parámetros y para el caso del `INSERT` hay sólo `15`. No revisé el `UPDATE`, pero si no tiene los mismos parámetros que el `INSERT` debes diferenciar los códigos sí o sí (el `INSERT` por una parte, quizá llamando a una función, y el `UPDATE` por otro). Esas mezclas son peligrosas y pasan estos errores o algunos más graves.

Comment: Sí, en el binding hay 16 parámetros, porque uno es el que se usa para saber si la consulta es de inserción o de modificación. Pero los parámetros para el insert y el update son idénticos (los he copiado y pegado uno a uno). Voy a separar la consulta en dos partes, a ver si así funciona, aunque no consigo entender porqué no funciona tal y como está.

Comment: @RaúlSoriaOrtiz revisa la edición de la respuesta, al final he añadido una posibilidad, pero lee bien la introducción a ese apartado.

Comment: Bueno, pues ya está creada y funcionando, aunque sólo he copiado y pegado. Muchas gracias @A.Cedano. Yo lo había hecho así pensando que era buena práctica, para reutilizar código. No se me ocurrirá hacerlo otra vez.

Comment: @RaúlSoriaOrtiz creo que es mejor diferenciar. No es lo mismo insertar, crear, modificar, borrar. Es mejor tener un método para cada cosa. Por en ejemplo en un `insert` te podría interesar devolver el último ID, mientras que en un `update` no. Además los parámetros son distintos para cada caso. Si trabajas desde el cliente, puedes poner un `action=>aquiAccion` identificando que tipo de operación ejecutar. Así todo queda más claro, ordenado y controlable.  Si la respuesta te ha ayudado la puedes marcar como resuelta. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, tendré que estudiar esto de los arrays, porque la verdad es que ahorra mucho código, aunque no queda tan "gráfico".  ¡Saludos!